# How to close Safari preference window using AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I am using the below script to enable developer menu.

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Safari"
            click menu item "Preferences…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Safari" of menu bar 1
            click button "Advanced" of toolbar 1 of window 1
            click checkbox "Show Develop menu in menu bar" of group 1 of group 1 of window 1
            -- delay 2
            keystroke "w" using {command down}  -- > not working
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

How to close the preference window? With `keystroke "w" using {command down}`, I am getting cannot `The document cannot be closed while the script is running.` error.

---

Also how to enable checkbox only if it is not enabled? Currently, if I run the script twice, it toggles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click the first button of the first window and check the `value` of the checkbox

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Safari"
            click menu item "Preferences…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Safari" of menu bar 1
            click button "Advanced" of toolbar 1 of window 1
            tell checkbox "Show Develop menu in menu bar" of group 1 of group 1 of window 1
                if value is 0 then click it
            end tell
            click button 1 of window 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Safari"
        set frontmost to true
    end tell
    keystroke "." using {command down}
end tell
```

Comment: BTW **⌘.** also works to close the Preferences window in Safari on macOS High Sierra.